# Button with data toggle collapse is opening modal, i dont know why

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in html + php:

```
<button style="margin-bottom: inherit;font-size: 14px;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo "info".$id_item1;?>">
               Information
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down" style="color: #002A41;"></i>
            </button>
            <div id="<?php echo "info".$id_item1;?>" class="collapse">
                <br>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form>


                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem is that my button is opening a modal and the collapse div at the same time and i dont know why happens this. The id of my modal is "myModal" and the id of the collapse div is different to this. I tried to use preventDefault but this avoid that the collapse div is visible.

Without the code php is not working still.

Comment: have you tried defining the collapse class css as hidden by default for the collapse div?

Comment: I cannot see it in your code, but my guess would be that both the modal and the div have the same id.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no, i tried with the examples of collapse in w3schools and the ids are totally differents, i have only a modal with the id "myModal"

Comment: @Sam0 my problem not is to show the div collapse, my problem is that the modal is show magically i dont know why

Comment: your `data-target` on the button is the same as the div id.. how is this different ?

Comment: The reason we cannot answer your question, and how to correct it, can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: can you check the modal initiation script? could be that one of the classes you have currently assigned is triggering it, or the problem is outside of the code given here.